# Keep kubernetes pod running until last user disconnects

Tags: kubernetes

I have a node.js container running on kubernetes that handles websocket connections that will normally be kept open until the user quits. Now when I do a rolling update or when the deployment scales down, is there a way to stop the pod from being killed until the last user has disconnected?

Comment: I doubt it. Once SIGTERM is sent to a container it has a configurable amount of time to drain before the rug is pulled from under its feet with SIGKILL (`spec.template.spec.terminationGracePeriodSeconds`). It would be better to accept this and reconnect your user in the case that this happens.

Comment: @spender so could I just set the terminationGracePeriodSeconds to half an hour and catch the SIGTERM in my application and then call process.exit once all the clients are disconnected? Or is that a bad practice?

Comment: That sounds like an abuse to me. It's going to mean that updates to your deployments will somewhat unpredictable. A better approach would be to gracefully disconnect your clients within the standard 30s and have them reconnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, Kubernetes does not support graceful connection closing.

`terminationGracePeriodSeconds` only define the timer before the Pod termination. It doesn't take care of Pod connections.

The only way to deal with rolling updates is to adapt your application to be able to switch clients to other pods transparently.

You may also want to take a look at [Disruption Budget](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/). It may help in some cases to have more reliable setup.

> A PDB specifies the number of replicas that an application can
>   tolerate having, relative to how many it is intended to have. For
>   example, a Deployment which has a .spec.replicas: 5 is supposed to
>   have 5 pods at any given time. If its PDB allows for there to be 4 at
>   a time, then the Eviction API will allow voluntary disruption of one,
>   but not two pods, at a time.
>
> PDBs cannot prevent [involuntary disruptions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/#voluntary-and-involuntary-disruptions) from occurring, but
>   they do count against the budget.
>
> Pods which are deleted or unavailable due to a rolling upgrade to an
>   application do count against the disruption budget, but *controllers*
>   (like *deployment* and *stateful-set*) are not limited by PDBs when doing
>   rolling upgrades – the handling of failures during application updates
>   is configured in the controller spec. (Learn about updating a
>   [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment).)
>
> When a pod is evicted using the eviction API, it is gracefully
>   terminated (see `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` in [PodSpec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#podspec-v1-core).)